# Elegant way to use VBA to call data from different sheets depending on user input

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning VBA, and am working to create a model that prompts a user for a type of risk and geographic region (done through a drop-down menu) and for a year (using the Input Box), and then pulls data from a different sheet that corresponds with the user input.  For example, if the user selected risk x, region y, and year 2025, the model would pull data off of a sheet that corresponds to risk x, region y, and year 2025.

Other than using long if/then statements, what are some more elegant (and somewhat learn-able for a new individual) ways to do this?  I don't want to write out 20-30 lines of if/then statements and am wondering how better coders would proceed.  Any ideas?  A sample part of my code is below.

```
Sub TryTwo()

    'For me to keep track of time complexity
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer


    'Declare main variables
    Dim riskType As String
    Dim region As String
    Dim year As Integer
    Dim yearCurrent As Integer: yearCurrent = 2015
    Dim currentVulnerabilityScore As Integer

    'Declare the different sheets
    Dim ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4, ws5, ws6, ws7, ws8, ws9 As Worksheet

    'Declare variables used in vlookup function for cells D3:D7
    Dim riskLookUpValue As Integer
    Dim regionLookUpValue As Integer

    'Set the different sheets in workbook
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LMC_Model")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Water_Risk")
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fire_Risk")
    Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Drought_Risk")
    Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Flood_Risk")
    Set ws6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sea Level Rise Risk")
    Set ws7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Facility_Supplier Tab")
    Set ws8 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Risks")
    Set ws9 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other")


    'Assign value to regionLookUpValue and input risk type into cell D3
    regionLookUpValue = Cells(2, 3).Value
    region = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(regionLookUpValue, ws9.Range("b3:c12"), 2)
    Cells(3, 4).Value = region

    'Assign value to riskLookUpValue and input risk type into cell D4
    riskLookUpValue = Cells(2, 4).Value
    riskType = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(riskLookUpValue, ws9.Range("b20:c24"), 2)
    Cells(4, 4).Value = riskType

    'assign year value in a loop that has user enter until right option found
    'Provide sentinal value of 0 to 'year' to ensure that user enters if statement and possibly do until loop
    year = 0
        If year = 0 Then
            year = InputBox("Please enter year (between 2016 and 2045)")
        End If

        Do
            If year < 2016 Or year > 2045 Then
                year = InputBox("Invalid year entry. Please enter year between 2016 and 2045")
        End If
        Loop Until year > 2015 And year < 2046
        Cells(5, 4).Value = year
```

Comment: Would an advanced filter work?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you envisage when you talk about "20-30 lines of if/then statements" - might help to add *some* of those here so we can tell what it is you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what you're asking Rivers. I'm going to answer your specific question then, further down, propose a different way of handling this.

In terms of your question, you could put your code in the `Workbook_SheetChange` event. That way you can test if the risk or region cells have been changed in the active sheet and make your changes as appropriate. You wouldn't need to use any `If` statements because each activated sheet would run the same piece of code on its sheet. Of course, if your ranges differ in each sheet then some extra coding would be required. The code below shows you how to do this, but read on because I don't think you're handling the task in the best way:

```
Option Explicit
Private mRiskSheets As Collection
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set mRiskSheets = New Collection

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Water_Risk")
    mRiskSheets.Add ws, ws.Name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fire_Risk")
    mRiskSheets.Add ws, ws.Name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drought_Risk")
    mRiskSheets.Add ws, ws.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim v(1 To 3, 1 To 1) As Variant

    'Test if activated sheet is a risk sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = mRiskSheets(Sh.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then

        'Check if the risk type or region cells were changed
        If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("C2,D2")) Is Nothing Then

            'It's a change we're interested in so set the year question
            If Len(ws.Range("D5").Text) = 0 Then
                v(3, 1) = InputBox("Please enter year (between 2016 and 2045)")
            Else
                v(3, 1) = ws.Range("D5").Value2
            End If

            Do
                If v(3, 1) < 2016 Or v(3, 1) > 2045 Then
                    v(3, 1) = InputBox("Invalid year entry. Please enter year between 2016 and 2045")
                End If
            Loop Until v(3, 1) > 2015 And v(3, 1) < 2046

            ' Acquire the values
            v(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Range("C2"), ws.Range("B3:C12"), 2)
            v(2, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Range("D2"), ws.Range("B20:C24"), 2)

            'Write the values
            ws.Range("D3:D5").Value = v

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I wouldn't be handling this in the way that you have. There are several difficulties:

1. Once the user has entered a year value, he has no opportunity to change it. Supposing, for example, he typed 2016 and meant to type 2017. How will he do that?
2. What if the user doesn't type an integer in the year `InputBox`, say 2016.5 or 2019*, then your code will throw an error.
3. In truth, your `InputBox` only acts like a cell, so you may as well have the user type the year directly into "D5" and just have some conditional formatting on it.
4. Without an `InputBox`, you could at least test for changes in any of the three cells "C2", "D2" or "D5". Whereas it's difficult to know when you want to handle a change event.
5. If there's any kind of problem with the risk type list then the code will throw an unhandled error because the look up failed.

If it were me, I'd have a `UserForm` which kept control over all of these issues. You could have one with 4 `ComboBoxes`: Risk category, risk type, region and year. Once all has been added as required then the user just hits a 'Fetch Data' `Button` and writes the data. It would mitigate the errors and allow for repeated inputs. Something like this:

[image: Sample UserForm]

In the UserForm designer add 4 `Comboboxes`, rename them as cboxRiskCat, cboxRiskType, cboxRegion and cboxYear, change their `ColumnCount` property to '2', and change the `Style` property to '2 - fmStyleDropDownList'. Add a `CommandButton` and rename it btnFetch.

Then add the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Private mRiskValues As Collection
Private mRegionValues As Collection
Private Sub btnFetch_Click()
    Dim v(1 To 3, 1 To 1) As Variant

    v(1, 1) = cboxRegion.Column(1)
    v(2, 1) = cboxRiskType.Column(1)
    v(3, 1) = cboxYear.Value

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cboxRiskCat.Column(1)).Range("D3:D5").Value = v
End Sub

Private Sub cboxRiskCat_Change()
    If cboxRiskCat.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cboxRiskCat.Column(1)).Activate
        cboxRegion.List = mRegionValues(cboxRiskCat.Column(1))
        cboxRegion.ListIndex = 0
        cboxRiskType.List = mRiskValues(cboxRiskCat.Column(1))
        cboxRiskType.ListIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim riskCat(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set mRegionValues = New Collection
    Set mRiskValues = New Collection

    'Populate the risk categories
    riskCat(1, 1) = "Water": riskCat(1, 2) = "Water_Risk"
    riskCat(2, 1) = "Fire": riskCat(2, 2) = "Fire_Risk"
    riskCat(3, 1) = "Drought": riskCat(3, 2) = "Drought_Risk"
    cboxRiskCat.List = riskCat

    ' Populate the risk types and regions
    For i = 1 To UBound(riskCat, 1)
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(riskCat(i, 2))
        v = ws.Range("B3:C12")
        mRegionValues.Add v, riskCat(i, 2)
        v = ws.Range("B20:C24")
        mRiskValues.Add v, riskCat(i, 2)
    Next

    'Populate the years in userform
    For i = 2016 To 2024
        cboxYear.AddItem i
    Next
    cboxYear.ListIndex = 0

    cboxRiskCat.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

You can show this UserForm simply by typing `UserForm1.Show` wherever you need it - probably in the `Workbook_Open` event.

I've only put three risk sheets in here. If you want more than that, then change the '3' in this line to however many sheets you have: `Dim riskCat(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As String`, and add further sheets as shown in the code just below this line.

Comment: I have to admit that I am really impressed by this.  I am teaching myself VBA as I go, and I am trying to follow along your advice as best as possible.  In regards to the `userform`, do you think its better to have year as a combobox or a field to enter in data?

Comment: I'd have a `ComboBox`, especially since there aren't heaps of years in the dropdown, because it's impossible for the user to enter incorrect data. It removes the need for you to instruct the reader on methods of entry, years limits, etc. (which is not really the user's concern) and it prevents you from having to anticipate the entry errors, even aspects as simple as '16' instead of '2016' would need to be handled.